# Does MongoDB shard router manipulate $in query?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

There's a collection named 'items' which is sharded with 3 shards

And 3 documents belong to each shard

- document with id:1 -> belong to shard1
- document with id:2 -> belong to shard2
- document with id:3 -> belong to shard3

When I query to router(mongos): items.find({id: { $in: [1,2,3] }})

Does router manipulate query for each shard?
ex) items.find({id: { $in: [1] }}) => route query to shard1

I want to know whether router just detects mapping shard or modify query for shard

Answer (score 1):

To my knowledge, the query is not manipulated in any way. Rather, the query is routed to any shards which may contain relevant data based on the shard key portion of the query. In the case where the query does not contain the shard key, the query will be routed to all of the shards.

For example, if you shard on the `id` field then `items.find({id: { $in: [1,2,3] }})` will be sent to `shard1`, `shard2`, and `shard3`, whereas `items.find({id: { $in: [1] }})` will only be sent to `shard1`. Additionally, the query `items.find({ref_id: { $in: [1] }})` will be sent to `shard1`, `shard2`, `shard3`, and any other shards you may have in your cluster.

The index scan on the shard key field should be fast enough that manipulating the query isn't even necessary, anyway!